# Need help using JQuery to prevent invisible anchor tags from being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, settimeout

On each of my portfolio items I have a div overlapping the top with it's opacity set to zero. When the user hovers over an item (or in the case of mobile, taps on one), the div transitions to opacity: 1. My problem is that if a user taps on any of the anchor tags located within this div (.portfolio-text), it takes them away from the page (at the moment href="#" so it refreshes the page) before they had the chance to even see the link.

My solution to this is to add a disabled class (thanks to Stephen Thomas below) to each of the anchor tags, and then remove the class with a jquery .hover() function. Unfortunately if the anchor tag is clicked simultaneously to the hover (like on mobile) then it still refreshes the page because I assume JQuery was too quick to remove the class.

To fix this I am trying to use the setTimeout function in my handler but it no longer removes the hidden class from my anchor elements, even though the console.log within that timeout function is still called.

I am not sure why the same line of code doesn't work just because there is a timeout function. If there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do please let me know.

EDIT:

I am rewriting this to be more clear and have included a codepen. My problem occurs on mobile phone screen sizes so you will want to view this on them or on an inspector.

https://codepen.io/colesam/full/NvLBPL/

html

```
<div class="full-page" id="portfolio-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2 class="center-text">My Portfolio</h2>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">
            <!-- offset col -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" id="portfolio-items">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <img src="http://basketball.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/placeholder.jpg" class="img-fluid"></img>
                        <div class="portfolio-text" id="test">
                            <h4>Wireframes</h4>
                            <a href="#" class="disabled">View</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>        
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <img src="http://basketball.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/placeholder.jpg" class="img-fluid"></img>
                        <div class="portfolio-text">
                            <h4>Coming Soon</h4>
                            <a href="#">View</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <img src="http://basketball.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/placeholder.jpg" class="img-fluid"></img>
                        <div class="portfolio-text">
                            <h4>Coming Soon</h4>
                            <a href="#">View</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    //  PORTFOLIO EVENT LISTENERS
    $('.portfolio-text').hover(
        function() {    //  hover on function
            setTimeout(function() {console.log('test'); $(this).children('a').removeClass('disabled');}, 50);
        },

        function() {    //  hover off function
            $(this).children('a').addClass('disabled');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out exactly what you're trying to do here, but you might want to look at the CSS rule `pointer-events: none` as a easier way to disable hyperlinks.

Comment: I'm also unable to see what you are trying to do, but href="#" is not a required attribute of an anchor tag. If your intent is to change the href using javascript at a latter point, then leaving it off of the html tag would work the way you want. Basicly a achor tag with no href= is a non-clickable anchor tag, and the simplest solution.

Comment: note I added responsive-design tag; as these are the people best suited to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) context, and it's out of scope within your closure. Why not try:

```
$('.portfolio-text').hover(function() {
    var $that = $(this);  // <--- HERE
    setTimeout(function() {
        // here 'this' is in a different context/scope
        $that.children('a').removeClass('disabled'); // USE HERE
    }, 50);
}, function() {
    $(this).children('a').addClass('disabled');
});
```

Alternatively, you could prevent those clicks perhaps with something like:

```
$('.portfolio-text').find('a:not(:visible)').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Perhaps start with that and build on it from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your first option worked. Why is it that $(this) is outside the scope of the setTimeout function? I thought that functions inside others have access to the same variables as the outside function.

Comment: Sorry, just saw this.  In `setTimeout` you are passing in a closure function as the first argument.  And then using `this` within that closure, in that case `this` no longer refers to the DOM element being hovered over.

Comment: Look up "Javascript Closures and 'this'" on SO or a search engine.  It's a good idea to get a better understanding of it to be more effective in JS.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing a site navigation menu, if so, why are you bothering with jquery?
You need to look into parent and child relationships, the parent div should stay activated while the child elements are hovered. I could provide you some code but first I need to make sure you are talking about a menu/navigation or if it's something else like a slideshow...

Answer (score 0):

You could do an Ajax on a desktop and use a link on the mobile. Just don't make the link clickable until after the first mobile click event, (or simulated hover event via touch the image) which makes the link visible.

Here is the basic idea. Use data-href for the url when they hover create a href attrib for the link ... when they unhover remove the href attrib from the link, ie href="". Now it works for mobile, and does not break the desktop, (as you can click the link after the hover).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
    //  PORTFOLIO EVENT LISTENERS
    $('.portfolio-text').hover(
        function() {    //  hover on function
        $(this).children('a').removeClass('disabled');
        // if mobile code
            $(this).children('a').attr("href", $(this).children('a').data( "href" ))
        // else
        // do ajax to get data to desktop browser divide ... the data is located at $(this).children('a').data( "href" ) for ajax.      
        },
    );
});
</script>

<div class="full-page" id="portfolio-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2 class="center-text">My Portfolio</h2>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">
            <!-- offset col -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" id="portfolio-items">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <img src="http://basketball.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/placeholder.jpg" class="img-fluid"></img>
                        <div class="portfolio-text" id="test">
                            <h4>Wireframes</h4>
                            <a data-href="wireframe.html" class="disabled">View</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>        
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <img src="http://basketball.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/placeholder.jpg" class="img-fluid"></img>
                        <div class="portfolio-text">
                            <h4>Coming Soon</h4>
                            <a data-href="portfolio2.html" >View</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <img src="http://basketball.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/placeholder.jpg" class="img-fluid"></img>
                        <div class="portfolio-text">
                            <h4>Coming Soon</h4>
                            <a data-href="portfolio2.html" >View</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```